# Sparklyr: Reading multiple Parquet files from S3 runs indefinitely

Tags: r, apache-spark, parquet, sparklyr, read-data

I'm working with Sparklyr to read Parquet files from an S3 bucket, and I'm facing an issue when trying to read multiple files. Reading a specific file works fine, but when attempting to read all files in a directory, the operation runs indefinitely. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```r
library(sparklyr)

config$sparklyr.connect.enablehivesupport <- FALSE

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)

sparklyr::spark_read_parquet( 
   sc,
   name = 'test',
   #path = 's3a://.../../data_01_04.parquet', #works fine
   #path = 's3a://.../../' #does not work
   #path = 's3a://.../../*.parquet' #does not work
 )
```

Am I missing something in the way I'm specifying the path for reading multiple files? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling the [recursive file lookup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#recursive-file-lookup)? And put the path ending with the folder name without /

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this would be a solution for SparkR and not sparklyr.